# Mac terminal and R show different GDAL versions

Tags: gdal, r, hdf, homebrew

I am trying to read a .hdf file into R using:

```
gdalUtils::get_subdatasets()
```

but I am left with this error:

```
ERROR 4: `/var/folders/24/9_h4zhq564g3zpvqp6jmbm0c0000gn/T//RtmpibWWKQ/MODIStsp/HDFs/MCD12Q1.A2014001.h18v04.006.2018146020544.hdf' not recognized as a supported file format.
gdalinfo failed - unable to open '/var/folders/24/9_h4zhq564g3zpvqp6jmbm0c0000gn/T//RtmpibWWKQ/MODIStsp/HDFs/MCD12Q1.A2014001.h18v04.006.2018146020544.hdf'.
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.data.frame': subscript out of bounds
In addition: Warning message:
In system(cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command '"/usr/local/Cellar/gdal/3.2.0/bin/gdalinfo" "/var/folders/24/9_h4zhq564g3zpvqp6jmbm0c0000gn/T//RtmpibWWKQ/MODIStsp/HDFs/MCD12Q1.A2014001.h18v04.006.2018146020544.hdf"' had status 1
```

I have had issues with gdal before, and was forced to download and use an older version of gdal to get the above function to work properly. In mac terminal, running

```
gdalinfo --version
```

returns

```
GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01
```

I assume there is a build problem here. When I run the following command in the R Console:

```
getGDALVersionInfo()
```

I am returned:

```
"GDAL 3.2.0, released 2020/10/26"
```

Is there a method to "unlink" gdal from R and then relink it to the older version noted in my Mac terminal?

There is a similar problem posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327253/rungdal-returns-gdalinfo-failed-unable-to-open-hdf-file), but the (unaccepted) answer is ambigious: "You need to uninstall gdalinfo on your Mac environment and use R gdalinfo and don't forget to restart your R after uninstall it"

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use another gdal installation by running `gdalUtils::gdal_setInstallation` --- but I have no experience with it.

Or you can work around it. Below I show how you might use `terra` to do so. It has some functionality to make it easy to deal with files with sub-datasets.

Example file

```
library(terra)
hdf4 <- system.file("external/test_modis.hdf", package="gdalUtils")
```

Read as a `SpatDataSet`

```
s <- sds(hdf4)
names(s)
#[1] "Fpar_1km"       "Lai_1km"        "FparLai_QC"     "FparExtra_QC"   "FparStdDev_1km" "LaiStdDev_1km" 

s
#class       : SpatDataSet 
#subdatasets : 6 
#dimensions  : 1200, 1200 (nrow, ncol)
#nlyr        : 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 
#resolution  : 926.6254, 926.6254  (x, y)
#extent      : -20015109, -18903159, 0, 1111951  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
#names       : Fpar_1km, Lai_1km, FparLai_QC, FparExtra_QC, FparStdDev_1km, LaiStdDev_1km
```

To use a subdataset, you can extract it using its index or name

```
a <- s[1]
b <- s["Lai_1km"]
x <- a * b
```

Or you can read the file as a `SpatRaster`. That is only possible if all subdatasets have the same extent and resolution. As is the case here:

```
r <- rast(hdf4)
names(r)
#[1] "Fpar_1km"       "Lai_1km"        "FparLai_QC"     "FparExtra_QC"   "FparStdDev_1km" "LaiStdDev_1km" 

r
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 1200, 1200, 6  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 926.6254, 926.6254  (x, y)
#extent      : -20015109, -18903159, 0, 1111951  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +R=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
#source(s)   : test_modis.hdf:MOD_Grid_MOD15A2:Fpar_1km  
#              test_modis.hdf:MOD_Grid_MOD15A2:Lai_1km  
#              test_modis.hdf:MOD_Grid_MOD15A2:FparLai_QC  
#              ... and 3 more source(s)
#names       : Fpar_1km, Lai_1km, FparLai_QC, FparExtra_QC, FparStdDev_1km, LaiStdDev_1km
```

Comment: The system.file call returns "", and using both sds() and rast() returns this error: GDAL Error 4: `/private/var/folders/24/9_h4zhq564g3zpvqp6jmbm0c0000gn/T/RtmpsjAkHH/MODIStsp/HDFs/MCD12Q1.A2014001.h18v04.006.2018146020544.hdf' not recognized as a supported file format.

Comment: Then I would uninstall (all version of) gdal, and get the latest `brew install gdal` and try again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598772/binding-gdal-with-r-on-osx-mac-cant-open-explore-h4-files-in-r This link explains the issue. Installing gdal by brew doesn't allow the get_subdatasets() call to work for mac.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that now when trying on mac. homebrew gdal does not have hdf support.